# I have a problem about the abiFilters configuration

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

the abiFilters configuration in app's build.gradle file in my project is :

```
ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi'
    }
```

that is I want my apk only support armeabi , but when I generated a apk for my project , I found there were armeabi and armeabi-v7a in my apk's lib dir . I feel confused, so is there anyone who can help me?

my android studio version is 3.4 and gradle version 4.10.1

Comment: Why `armeabi`? All ARM-based Android devices for the last 8-9 years have used ARMv7 or later. Also keep in mind that Google Play now requires you to provide 64-bit libraries if your app contains any 32-bit native libraries. That is, if you support `armeabi` or `armeabi-v7a` then you must also support `arm64-v8a`.

Comment: This problem has been resolved.I made a mistake in my project . Now in my project i use armebai-v7a only, the 64-bit libraries will be supported later.Thanks for your reminding.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify, which one do you need exactly.

```
abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
```